# SQLite vertical stack

Tags: sql, sqlite, sas

I have two tables:

```
data1
A B
0 1
0 1

data2
A B
2 3
2 3
```

I want to create a 4th table which is a vertical stack of the above:

```
data3
A B
0 1
0 1
2 3
2 3
```

I am unfamiliar with SQLite, and am currently using SAS, where this can be done using a DATA step query:

```
data data3;
set data1 data2;
run;
```

How can I do this in SQLite?

Comment: To the downvoter, please let me know how I can improve this question! I'll gladly do so (or delete) if it is felt a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
create table data3
    select A, B from data1 union all
    select A, B from data2;
```

Note that in SQL, you don't need to create a new table to do this.  You can just put the `union all` in a subquery:

```
select d.*
from (select A, B from data1 union all
      select A, B from data2
     ) d;
```

This is often a better idea than creating another table.

Comment: Can this be done without writing out individual column names? (Let's assume I know they are the same in both datasets)

Comment: @Chuck yes, just do `select *`, as long as both tables have the same structure

Comment: Of course (*facepalm*). Will this be faster than the other answer?

Comment: @Chuck . . . It is a good practice to list the column names when combining tables using `union all`.  It is not *necessary* but defensive coding is a good idea.  As for performance, if you are creating the table, then two inserts or one insert are probably going to be pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and  [`INSERT INTO table SELECT ...`](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) queries, like:

```
CREATE TABLE data3 AS SELECT * FROM data1;
INSERT INTO data3 SELECT * FROM data2;
```